# Error when creating a Spring Boot project from command line with mvn archetype: generate

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I want to create a Spring Boot project with this command in command line: `mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=com.dgs -DarchetypeArtifactId=spring-boot-quickstart -DarchetypeVersion=1.0.0 -DgroupId=com.dgs -DartifactId=sampleapp -Dversion=1.0.0-SNAPSHOT -DinteractiveMode=false`

And I get this error: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.1.1:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: The desired archetype does not exist (com.dgs:spring-boot-quickstart:1.0.0)

What can I do to resolve the problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you refer to https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.supermanhub/spring-boot-quick-start-archetype/1.0

In this case the `-DarchetypeGroupId`, `-DarchetypeArtifactId` and `-DarchetypeVersion` are wrong

In maven central repository its defined as:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.github.supermanhub</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-quick-start-archetype</artifactId>
   <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Just to complement your answer (that I believe correct) I would like to remind also about official [Initializr](https://start.spring.io/). It can generate a complete project for you including pom.xml with required dependencies. Great option if command line is not a mandatory deal.

Comment: Yes, @IvkinIgor is totally right, usually people start with https://start.spring.io/ and generate spring microservices from there, I haven't mentioned it because it doesn't appear in the question :)